# Retrieving Data From Associated Toxi Table

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

I'm retrieving my data for part of my site with a typical MySQL query and echoing out the results from various fields etc etc from my main table whose structure is not important but which has a unique id which is 'job_id'

In order to have multiple catagories associated with that 'job_id' i have employed a toxi solution which associates catgories to each 'job_id'.

```
TABLE `tags` (
`tag_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`tag_name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `tag_relational` (
`job_id` INT NOT NULL, 
`tag_id` INT NOT NULL
)
```

What i want to do is, when i echo out the info from the main table (using 'job_id') i also want to echo all the catagories which that job_id is matched against.

The query below only returns the first catagory(tag_name) that the job_id is listed against, when it should be up to six (at the moment):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tags t
JOIN tag_relational r   
ON t.tag_id=r.tag_id
WHERE r.job_id = $job_id";

$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$cats=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

In my code i'm using this to echo out the matched catagories:

```
<?php echo $cats['tag_name'];?>
```

Can someone explain how i can get ALL the catagory names to echo out rather than just the first?
Thanks
Dan

BTW, apologies to **mu is too short** who kindly answered my question when i had dummy/less complete information above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to list the category names, then you could use [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) sort of like this:

```
select b.*,
       group_concat(c.category_name order by c.category_name separator ' ,') as cats
from business b
join tbl_works_categories w on b.id = w.bus_id
join categories c on w.category_id = c.category_name
where ...
group by b.id
```

You'd need a proper WHERE clause of course. That will give you the usual stuff from `business` and the category names as a comma delimited list in `cats`.

If you need the category IDs as well, then two queries might be better: one to get the `business` information and a second to collect the categories:

```
select w.bus_id, c.category_id, c.category_name
from tbl_works_categories w
join categories c
where w.bus_id IN (X)
```

where `X` is a comma delimited list of `business` ID values. Then you'd patch things up on the client side.

Comment: No its just the catagory names i need/want. Thanks. So i just insert my current Where query into the above and is 'cats' then a variable that i echo out, or how do i treat that? Thanks again, Dan

Comment: @Dan: Right, just add your WHERE and then `cats` should come out like any other column.

Comment: Brilliant. I'll give it a go and hopefully mark this up as answered shortly. Thank you very much for your help. Dan

Comment: I have edited my question and put a bit more work in myself. Apologies for not doing this earlier. Dan

Comment: @Dan: The problem is in the PHP then? You should be able to `while ($cats = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ...` to get all six rows out.

Comment: One further question: how can i define a seperator within my query for the returned results? I can't get group_concat to work?

Comment: @Dan: What happens with your `group_concat`? Do you have a GROUP BY clause?

Comment: @muistooshort let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2021/discussion-between-dan-and-mu-is-too-short)